# Asking for proper usage of a language feature

Tags: discussion

Today, I <s>discovered</s> have been made aware of a feature of SQL that looks very weird to me. I generally trust the people behind SQL Server, so I'm wondering what might be a good use case of that feature.

That's dangerously close to being too opinion based, but I'm sure you can see how it's not as bad as asking if the header of a website should be font size 16 or 17. I think my question would be closer to asking for best practices, which I've seen around.

Without being able to tell me if my question is valid (as I haven't asked it yet), would you straight out of the gate tell me I shouldn't ask something like that?

Comment: "Good use case" suggest a primarily opinion based question which is off-topic

Comment: Nope. probably shouldn't ask that.

Comment: *I think my question would be closer to asking for best practices, which I've seen around.* Yes, but a lot of those are off topic too. They just don't get closed as often. Better to ask for an explanation of what it's for and include why the feature comes across as weird to you. A good answer will likely include a use case to help explain it.

Comment: It would be great if you showed that you've actually read the documentation of the feature on MSDN or wherever...

Comment: I tried finding resources on the feature, but since I don't understand it properly, I can't find what I'm looking for. To make it simple, you can have table having two foreign keys linking the same column to two different tables. So basically saying "If you're in table Toto, you must be in table Foo and Bar." If I want to get information on that, searching "having two foreign key on the same column" link to people asking if you can have two foreign keys pointing to the same column. (two-to-one instead of one-to-two)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/1228).  Also, that's nothing to do with Sql Server, that's just how you denormalize data, and can be expected in the real world, which is messy.